# Dirichlet series of the divisor function

Tags: dirichlet-series

I want to show that the Dirichlet series of the divisor function $\sigma_k$ converges absolutly.

I have found this:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{n^{s}}=\zeta(s)\zeta(s-k)$$ for all $s\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\text{Re}(s)>k+1$.

I thought: The series convergs absolutly as a product of absolutly convergent series (zeta-series). Is that right?

If yes: Where can I find a proof of this equation?
If no: How can this be shown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^k$ is a multiplicative function, hence by [Euler's product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) or just by convolution of Dirichlet's series we have

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^k}{n^s}=\zeta(s)\zeta(s-k)$$

as soon as the involved series are absolutely convergent.

Comment: For which $s$ this holds?

Comment: @user365151: *as soon as the involved series are absolutely convergent*, hence for $\text{Re}(s)>k+1$.

Comment: Thank you! So the left series is absolutely convergent because the right side is absolutely convergent because it is a product of absolutely convergent zeta series?

Comment: @user365151: exactly.

Comment: @user365151: there is no big difference, since if $s=\sigma+it$ we have $$\left\|\frac{1}{n^s}\right\|=\frac{1}{\|n^\sigma\cdot n^{it}\|}=\frac{1}{n^\sigma}.$$

Comment: @user365151: you can still compute the Cauchy product of two series, also if you do not call them *Dirichlet series* as they are.

Comment: How do you get the answer by Euler product?